# spinner.setSelection() giving problems while using with 2 spinners

Tags: android, spinner

I am having an issue in my app where I am using 2 spinners, 1 for morning shift time & 2nd for evening shift time. Now I want that when I select morning shift time or evening shift time, each time the opposite spinner resets itself. Like if I select morning time than evening shift time (if changed) again goes back to setSelection(0) (which is Evening text written) and vice versa. I am using setSelection(0) on setOnItemSelectedListener of each spinner to reset the value but each time it resets both the spinners first and then again select 1 time from anyone.
How can I overcome this issue? I have also tried using boolean variables but didn't work for me

```
spinner_mrg.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
     public void onItemSelected()
    spinner_eve.setSelection(0);
    time = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

 }

spinner_eve.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
     public void onItemSelected()
    spinner_mrg.setSelection(0);
    time = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
   }
```

Comment: fixed or still facing same issue?

Comment: Yes, the issue still persists

Comment: Yes, the issue still persists. It automatically resets both the spinners. I think that setSelection(0) sets the value as 0 which leads to call the setOnItemSelectedListener of 2nd spinner automatically as by default spinner selects the 0 position value disregard of calling setOnItemSelectedListener() of it. I have tried using OnitemClickListener also, but it doesn't work